# How to auto generate bulk greeting cards from excel/csv data

Tags: adobe-indesign, automation, data-visualisation

I am trying to bulk generate greeting cards from an excel(or csv) table in which multiple people have generated customized messages for each recipient.

- Each card can have a different number of people who have written a message.
- Each message-writer has their own column in the excel file.

Ideally, I would like each message writer to have their own default
   font.  As there will be variable number of messages (of varying
   length) on each card,  I need some sort of auto-arrange so that all
   the messages fit and scale onto a single card/image.

Does anyone know of any program that can help translate this table into a graphical layout.  I'm open to fully programatic solutions (D3.js maybe?) or ways to work with existing graphic design apps like inDesign.

Comment: You can do this by scripting in InDesign or even use the data merge tools https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/data-merge.html

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for Data Merge.

From Adobe:

> About **data merge**
>
> To create form letters, envelopes, or mailing labels, you merge a data
>   source file with a target document. Data merge is also referred to as
>   mail merge.

**Steps**

Most of this can be managed in the Data Merge Panel.

1. Create or open the document you’ll be using as the target document.
2. Choose Window > Utilities > Data Merge.
3. Choose Select Data Source from the Data Merge panel menu.
4. To change delimited text options, select Show Import Options.
5. Locate the data source file, and click Open. If you
   selected Show Import Options, change the delimiter and encoding
   options as necessary, and then click OK.
6. The data fields appear in
   the Data Merge panel.

Determine how you want the final document to look, so that you know which fields are necessary to accomplish the merge. For example, if you are creating a postcard that is mailed to customers, you can use the following data fields:

```
<<Company Name>><<Address>><<City>>, <<State>><<Postal Code>>
```

You can create these fields on your page by dragging and dropping items from the Data Merge panel (once a data source has been selected).

You can preview the records to make sure that the target document will look the way you intend.

Lastly, merge the target document with the data source file, or export to PDF.

Source [Adobe Help Reference](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/data-merge.html)

Further info:

- Video: [YouTube HowTo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQ2AchJ3434)
- Detailed article:
  [Creative Pro: Designing Data](http://creativepro.com/indesign-how-designing-data/)

Comment: Given that I'm not sure how long each message will be,  is there a way to auto arrange the text boxes after the text has been imported so that there is no overlap?  Also, some of the columns in the csv might not be populated for some rows,  will that text box just be blank in InDesign and can auto arrange deal with this (by not arranging the blank text boxes?)

Comment: It's best to set up on item (i.e., greeting card) as a template. The Data Merge can then create a new document with multiple instances on a page for easy printing. It also lets you preview the data.

Comment: I don't think you can auto-arrange easily without a script. It you put all the text into one text frame, it will reflow automatically.